# Add remote server as git remote

Tags: git, permissions, git-remote

I tried to add a Git remote with

```
git remote add remote-server ssh://domain_name.com/opt/test/testapp.git

git push remote-server master
```

The problem is that I am trying to push from the local server as user 'kute', and the file `opt/test/testapp.git` is owned by another user, say 'test'.
So, when I run `git push remote-server master`, I get the following permission issue:

> fatal: Unable to create temporary file: Permission denied error:
>   pack-objects died of signal 13 error: failed to push some refs to

Is there any solution to this permission issue?

Comment: The you who own the repo have to give you the permission. Then you can do this.

Comment: I didn't get what you said. my issue is , the repo in the localhost is owned by me and i want to push the changes to remote server and that repo is owned by some other user

Comment: ya, you have to have permission to push on that remote server otherwise you can't.

Comment: I can ssh into the server by my username and then sudo su - test will work for me. is there any way to give username in 'git push ..'? or any common user that have persmission(like git user)? or can i give any group permission ?

Answer (score 0):

You must not push directly to remote repository own by another person.

You must use a "share" repository and add your public ssh key in the .ssh/authorized_keys file of the unix user that own the "share" repository.